# 'onecolumn' works on one TeX installation but not another

Tags: errors

I recently installed TexLive 2020 on both my personal and work computer, the two are linked to the same repository which stores my TeX documents. I am using a documentclass 'ieeeconf' provided by a conference I wish to submit to; it's an explicit file that I pass as the documentclass.

I am drafting a paper and have been using the 'onecolumn' option to have a single column paper. However, in the installation of my personal computer, the output is still in a two-column format. I have no clue why this is the case, since I am compiling the exact same latex code, pulled from the same git repository. This is very annoying because I do not want to be afraid of getting different outputs when I work on different computers (not just in this case, but in general).

Both computers run ""/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "root".tex" for compilation.

I know I am not providing much info, but I really have no clue where to start debugging this problem. Does anyone have any ideas of what I could look into?

Best,

-Tusike

EDIT: File List outputs:

Correctly working computer:

```
*File List*
../../templates/acc/ieeeconf.cls
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
packages.tex
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
colortbl.sty    2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
subcaption.sty    2020/08/23 v1.3g Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/09/12 v3.5b Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/09/17 v2.1b caption3 kernel (AR)
 amsmath.sty    2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
    acro.sty    2020/05/10 v3.2 typeset acronyms and other abbreviations
   expl3.sty    2020-10-05 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xparse.sty    2020-10-05 L3 Experimental document command parser
xparse-generic.tex
l3keys2e.sty    2020-10-05 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
zref-abspage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi package
with kernel methods
zref-totpages.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module totpages for zref (HO)
zref-lastpage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module lastpage for zref (HO)
atveryend.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
translations.sty    2020/04/28 v1.8b internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (
CN)
scrlfile.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    cite.sty    2015/02/27  v 5.5
    tikz.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
     pgf.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgfsys.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgffor.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
      bm.sty    2019/07/24 v1.2d Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
nicematrix.sty    2020/10/06 v5.4 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
../../commands.tex
commands.tex
../../glossary.tex
    root.acr
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
source/abstract.tex
source/introduction.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_whitenoise.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_functionals.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_IGO.tex
    ueuf.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 Euler Fraktur
source/Problem/problem.tex
source/openloop/openloop.tex
source/openloop/openloop_pde.tex
source/openloop/openloop_feynmankac.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_pde.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_feynmankac.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_probabilities.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_inputs.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_cma.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_algorithm.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_interpretation.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_initialstate.tex
source/discussion/discussion.tex
source/discussion/discussion_differences.tex
source/discussion/discussion_differencesPractical.tex
source/discussion/discussion_future.tex
source/conclusions.tex
    root.bbl
  ts1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for TS1/ptm.
    root.acr
 ***********
```

Incorrectly working computer:

````
*File List*
../../templates/acc/ieeeconf.cls
  ot1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ptm.
packages.tex
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  pdftex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
colortbl.sty    2020/01/04 v1.0e Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2020/10/01 v2.5c Tabular extension package (FMi)
graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
subcaption.sty    2020/10/07 v1.3j Sub-captions (AR)
 caption.sty    2020/10/26 v3.5g Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2020/10/21 v2.2e caption3 kernel (AR)
 amsmath.sty    2020/09/23 v2.17i AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
  amsthm.sty    2020/05/29 v2.20.6
    acro.sty    2020/11/08 v3.2a typeset acronyms and other abbreviations
   expl3.sty    2020-10-27 L3 programming layer (loader) 
l3backend-pdftex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
  xparse.sty    2020-10-27 L3 Experimental document command parser
l3keys2e.sty    2020-10-27 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
zref-abspage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module abspage for zref (HO)
zref-base.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module base for zref (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
etexcmds.sty    2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
atbegshi.sty    2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi package
with kernel methods
zref-totpages.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module totpages for zref (HO)
zref-lastpage.sty    2020-07-03 v2.32 Module lastpage for zref (HO)
atveryend.sty    2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery package
with kernel methods
translations.sty    2020/11/08 v1.9 internationalization of LaTeX2e packages (C
N)
scrlfile.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (file load hooks)
scrlfile-hook.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (using LaTeX hooks)
 scrlogo.sty    2020/09/21 v3.32 KOMA-Script package (logo)
etoolbox.sty    2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
    cite.sty    2015/02/27  v 5.5
    tikz.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
     pgf.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgfsys.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
  pgffor.sty    2020/10/01 v3.1.6a (3.1.6a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
      bm.sty    2019/07/24 v1.2d Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
algorithm.sty    2009/08/24 v0.1 Document Style `algorithm' - floating environm
ent
   float.sty    2001/11/08 v1.3d Float enhancements (AL)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
nicematrix.sty    2020/11/08 v5.6 Enhanced arrays with the help of PGF/TikZ
textcomp.sty    2020/02/02 v2.0n Standard LaTeX package
../../commands.tex
commands.tex
../../glossary.tex
    root.acr
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
translations-basic-dictionary-english.trsl    (english translation file `transl
ations-basic-dictionary')
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
  ot1pcr.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/pcr.
source/abstract.tex
source/introduction.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_whitenoise.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_functionals.tex
source/preliminaries/preliminaries_IGO.tex
    ueuf.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 Euler Fraktur
source/Problem/problem.tex
source/openloop/openloop.tex
source/openloop/openloop_pde.tex
source/openloop/openloop_feynmankac.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_pde.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_feynmankac.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_probabilities.tex
source/closedloop/closedloop_inputs.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_cma.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_algorithm.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_interpretation.tex
source/pi2_igo/pi2_igo_initialstate.tex
source/discussion/discussion.tex
source/discussion/discussion_differences.tex
source/discussion/discussion_differencesPractical.tex
source/discussion/discussion_future.tex
source/conclusions.tex
    root.bbl
  ts1ptm.fd    2001/06/04 font definitions for TS1/ptm.
    root.acr
 ***********
​```
````

Comment: Can you please include `\listfiles` in the preamble of your document and show the resulting `*File List*` section from your log from *both* machines?

Comment: I added the list of files from both computers.

Comment: Using an online text comparison tool, I see there are different versions of the following packages: subcaption, caption, caption3, acro, expl3, xparse, l3keys2e, translations, nicematrix. I will see if I can update them (there was about 2 weeks difference between the two TexLive installations), but should any of these affect whether the documentclass template acknowledges the onecolumn option or not?

Comment: Can you check the LaTeX versions on both machines? (The LaTeX version is mentioned at the start of the `.log` file, e.g. I have `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2` on my machine). Maybe it's something like https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422 (which if I understand correctly was introduced by the fix for https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/414 in `2020-10-01 PL 2`, so if the machine where things work has `2020-10-01 PL1` or below that might explain stuff).

Comment: The correctly working versions says "Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.10.21)". The version of the incorrect one is the same, but the preloaded format is pdflatex 2020.11.20.

Comment: Ah sorry, we'll need to see the LaTeX *version* logged a few lines below that in the `.log` file. It should look like `LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>` (not the engine version or the format date).

Comment: Ah, I might have misunderstood. The correct one is "LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 1, L3 programming layer <2020-10-05> xparse <2020-03-03>". The incorrect one changes to patch level 2, and L3 programming layer <2020-10-27>.

Comment: OK. This could indeed be https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422. How do you load your class in your document (i.e. what is the exact `\documentclass` call) and how do you pass the option `onecolumn` to the class?

Comment: The exact call is "\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{../../templates/acc/ieeeconf}" where the ieeeconf file I have downloaded a while ago from paperplaza. But it definitely seems to be some issue with this file being loaded as relative path, if I change it to "\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{IEEEtran}", the output of the two computers looks the same. I would only want to keep the original documentclass because the margins there nicely fit my text...

Comment: OK, I'm pretty sure this is the bug reported at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422. If I understand correctly a fix is in the making and should hopefully be released soon. The linked bug report also contains two possible workarounds (I'm not too sure about the `\def\input@path` one, but the `latexrelease` one looks solid). Alternatively, you could move `ieeeconf.cls` from `../../templates/acc/` directly into the document directory, so that you can load the class as `\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{ieeeconf}` which should avoid the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have now tried directly using the template, and it seems to work fine. I now read that using relative paths is bad practice, but I'm unsure how else to use the same template across multiple documents in different locations.. Anyway, thank you very much for the help, if you copy this last message as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: If you want to use a class in several documents and the class is not available for installation from your TeX distribution, you can install it in a local TDS tree. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/35864 and https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are having looks very much as though it is caused by https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues/422 (a bug in LaTeX 2010-10-01 PL2).

If I understand correctly a fix is in the making and should hopefully be released soon.

The linked bug report also contains two possible workarounds (I'm not too sure about the `\def\input@path` one, but the `latexrelease` one looks solid).

Alternatively, you could move `ieeeconf.cls` from `../../templates/acc/` directly into the document directory, so that you can load the class as `\documentclass[conference, onecolumn]{ieeeconf}` which should avoid the issue. If you want to use the `ieeeconf` class in multiple documents, it might be worth looking into installing the class into a local TeX tree ([Where do I place my own .sty or .cls files, to make them available to all my .tex files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/35864), https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-inst-wlcf). Using relative paths to load a class or package is always a bit dangerous.